# How to checkpoint tf.data Dataset objects?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

When checkpointing during training (in case of crash/etc) I save the graph and parameters, but it's not clear how to do the same to the new `tf.data` objects used for input.

Is there a straightforward way to also checkpoint these such that I can continue the current epoch, or restore the shuffle state (maybe from a seed?)

Comment: For non-shuffled datasets, it seems like you could save the number of global calls, and have a throwaway op to "seek" through the dataset to where you were, but this goes out the window with `.shuffle()`.

Comment: machinaut: this is likely extremely slow though, for large datasets.

Comment: has the venerable mrry's solution below worked for you? I am also very interested in resuming training without repeating seen data within the current epoch. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`tf.contrib.data.make_saveable_from_iterator()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/make_saveable_from_iterator) function takes a `tf.data.Iterator` object and gives you back a "saveable object" that can be saved using a [`tf.train.Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver). It saves the entire state of the iterator, including any shuffled data.

The following example code shows how to add a simple iterator to the same checkpoint used for variables:

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(10)
iterator = ds.make_initializable_iterator()

# [Build the training graph, using `iterator.get_next()` as the input.]

# Build the iterator SaveableObject.
saveable_obj = tf.contrib.data.make_saveable_from_iterator(iterator)

# Add the SaveableObject to the SAVEABLE_OBJECTS collection so
# it will be saved automatically using a Saver.
tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.SAVEABLE_OBJECTS, saveable_obj)

# Create a saver that saves all objects in the `tf.GraphKeys.SAVEABLE_OBJECTS`
# collection.
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  while continue_training:

    # [Perform training.]

    if should_save_checkpoint:
      saver.save(sess, ...)
```

Note that the iterator checkpointing support is currently (as of TensorFlow 1.8) in an experimental state, so the checkpoint format may change from one version to the next.

Comment: Thanks @mrry. I managed to get this to work on a single worker with the following code snippet:     iterator = data_set.make_initializable_iterator()   # save dataset state.
    saveable_obj = tf.contrib.data.make_saveable_from_iterator(iterator)
    tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.SAVEABLE_OBJECTS, saveable_obj)
    tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TABLE_INITIALIZERS, iterator.initializer), however does this work in a distributed setting? With inspect_checkpoint I only see one iterator_state variable, Iterator:0-state (DT_VARIANT) [].

Comment: Dear mrry: I checked today that this doesn't work even for single worker non-distributed mode.  What I did is create a dummy tfrecord file with 1000 examples, with int64 label enumerating 0 through 999, and tf.Print the labels during training. After training an initial model with 100 examples, I restarted training without deleting checkpoint, but the tf.Print output of the label tensor is still 0 ~ 100.

Comment: just realized I need to put your user tag in the front for the system to consume properly. Please see my last question above (I think once single worker case is figured out I have a way to do it in distributed setting). Sorry for the spam.